# Javascript link SEO

Tags: javascript, dom

I have a page where in a photo and description link is there, i want replace the hard coded link with a javascript,which will add them,as i dont want the search engine to scroll the links.I dont wanna use "nofollow" attribute.How to code it in js.

Comment: Why don't you want to use "nofollow"? If you have static links on the page, it will load faster than if you generate the links with JavaScript, and search engines will respect "nofollow".

Comment: If you want search engines to keep out, use robots.txt, don't assume that "No JavaScript" means "A search engine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I may have misunderstood you - I thought you want to *keep* search engine visibility. Can you clarify which one you want? If you *don't* want the links and images to be indexed, I'd say `nofollow` is in fact your best friend. A JavaScript based solution is of course doable, but will lock out clients that don't have it enabled.

**Original answer**

The usual way would be to keep the link in a standard `href` attribute, and adding a JavaScript `onclick` event that does its thing using the href, and returns `false` so the "normal" link doesn't get triggered.

This leaves a search engine-readable link in place, and enables clients with JavaScript disabled to still somehow access the image.

This technique is also known as [progressive enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised is Google couldn't handle links created from Javascript. If you want to keep the linked pages unindexed, use nofollow on the link or noindex on the target page or add them to robots.txt.